# Create disabled page property dynamicallyin a CQ page

Tags: extjs, aem

I have a page X where I set a page property "type=myValue" using a drop down in page properties.

What I need is that when I create child page under page X, the child page should get the same property set for itself. This property should be disabled for end users to edit.

Can this be done without going through a workflow ? I need this to be set as soon as the page is created. ! Maybe some ext-js function on the child page template ?

Comment: How do u intend to use the property x that is present in the page ?

Comment: I need to use the property 'type' while performing jcr:search on the child pages. But it is present in the parent page (X) only. Thats why I need a way to create it dynamically while creating the child page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not want to create a workflow, there are 2 other ways which are available through which this functionality can be achieved.

- Creating an event handler that listens to Node Added event
- Creating your custom servlet that handles the page creation activity by overriding the handler(CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.createPage) for the Create Page button instead of the default command.

For quick reference, you can find details of implementing the event handler [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5492913).